# How can I get a list of folders in the running directory and assign them each to a varible?

Tags: linux, bash, file, scripting, permissions

I'm wanting to make a script that will be able to scan through a directory with a lot of folders and change the permissions of each folder as it goes through. I'm also going to make it so that it prompts me after the permissions changed to ask if I want to continue. Currently I'm trying to find a way to do as the title suggests so I can get started on the rest of it. New to bash, thanks for t he help!

Comment: Does `find . -type d -ok chmod $newperm {} \;` do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can added a `read response' and if/then check on the response for your prompting, but a list of directories can be done in a for loop or in an array.

The array:

```
# only directories, remove the trailing /.
declare -a dirs=($(ls -d */.|sed 's;/.;;')
```

The for loop:

```
for d in */.; do
   echo "commands here for $d directory"
done
```

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Especially when there is no reason to do so (and there isn't since `a=(*/)` will set up the array correctly, without stripping `/` obviously, without `ls`).

Comment: Awesome, this should work, I'll try it. Thank you very much for your time!